# JavaScript IE 9: Custom sort function

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, sorting, internet-explorer-9

In IE 9, if I type this in the console:

```
[1, 4, 2, 3].sort(function (a, b) { return a < b; });
```

The resulting array is: `[1, 4, 2, 3]`.

If I do this in FF/Chrome, I get it, reverse-sorted: `[4, 3, 2, 1]`.

How come this doesn't work in IE?

**EDIT: Is there a function out there that abstracts these browser differences? In other words, is there a function I can pass function(a, b) { return a < b; } in and get the same result in all browsers? Any open-source stuff?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782893/ie9-javascript-sort-order-why

Comment: I see this answer you have linked but I don't understand how to make it work in IE like it does in FF/Chrome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe because the function is supposed to return `-1` if `a` is smaller, `0` if they are equal, and `1` if `a` is larger (or vice versa if you want reverse order). **Edit:** In fact, it must be zero, a positive or negative number (as @pimvdb pointed out, and that's what I make use of in the example below). Your function will never return `-1` though and that might create problems.

Consider `1` and `3`. Your function returns `1` for `1 < 3`, which is ok, but returns `0` for `3 < 1`. In one case the number are different, in the other you are saying that they are equal.

That FF/Chrome sort it in reverse order might be due to the sorting algorithm they are using.

Try:

```
[1, 4, 2, 3].sort(function (a, b) { return b - a; });
```

**Update:** To substantiate this, we can have a look at the specification, Section [15.4.4.11   Array.prototype.sort(comparefn](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.4.4.11)),  where the properties are given which have to be fulfilled by a comparison function:

> A function *comparefn* is a consistent comparison function for a set of values `S` if all of the requirements below are met for all values *a*, *b*, and *c* (possibly the same value) in the set `S`: The notation *a* <<sub>CF</sub> *b* means *comparefn(a,b)* < 0; *a* =<sub>CF</sub> *b* means *comparefn(a,b)* = 0 (of either sign); and *a* ><sub>CF</sub> *b* means *comparefn(a,b)* > 0.
>
> - Calling *comparefn(a,b)* always returns the same value v when given a specific pair of values *a* and *b* as its two arguments. Furthermore, Type(*v*) is Number, and *v* is not **NaN**. Note that this implies that exactly one of *a* <<sub>CF</sub> *b*,
>     *a* =<sub>CF</sub> *b*, and *a* ><sub>CF</sub> *b* will be true for a given pair of *a* and *b*.
> - Calling *comparefn(a,b)* does not modify the **this** object.
> - *a* =<sub>CF</sub> *a* (reflexivity)
> - If  *a* =<sub>CF</sub> *b*, then *b* =<sub>CF</sub> *a* (symmetry)
> - If  *a* =<sub>CF</sub> *b* and *b* =<sub>CF</sub> *c*, then *a* =<sub>CF</sub> *c*  (transitivity of  =<sub>CF</sub>)
> - If  *a* <<sub>CF</sub> *b* and *b* <<sub>CF</sub> *c*, then *a* <<sub>CF</sub> *c* (transitivity of  <<sub>CF</sub>)
> - If  *a* ><sub>CF</sub> *b* and *b* ><sub>CF</sub> *c*, then *a* ><sub>CF</sub> *c*  (transitivity of  ><sub>CF</sub>)
>
> NOTE The above conditions are necessary and sufficient to ensure that *comparefn* divides the set S into equivalence classes and that these equivalence classes are totally ordered.

Comment: +1 Although it's rather a negative/positive/zero number. Yours doesn't always return `-1`, `1` or `0` either :)

Comment: ES5 #15.4.4.11 - sais you must return `1`, `0` or `-1` in custom sort function. http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf

Comment: @c69: As far as I understood it, this is what the internal compare function returns. A function passed as parameter just has to follow these rules: *The notation a <CF b means comparefn(a,b) < 0; a =CF b means comparefn(a,b) = 0 (of either sign); and a >CF b means comparefn(a,b) > 0*. But thanks for the reference!